# What script font is this found here?

Tags: font-identification

What font is found here in the following image?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [Vivaldi](http://www.fonts.com/findfonts/detail.htm?productid=175276) to me, specifically, the [URW++ or Elsner+Flake versions](https://www.myfonts.com/search/vivaldi/fonts/).

[image: Rugs]

Comment: Ah. Thank you. Does look like it; except for the g. It's really close. Must have been modified.

Comment: It looks like that G could even be combinaion of 2 other characters of the vivaldi font. ( the G "original" image )

Comment: @Lollero Actually, the version of Vivaldi I have has that first particular "g". According to [myfonts.com](http://new.myfonts.com/search/vivaldi/fonts/), the URW++ and Elsner+Flake versions of the font has that weird one-story "g", the other foundries have a two-storey "g".

Comment: @ghoppe interresting.

Comment: "A two-story g." I've never heard it described that way before. Interesting and evocative.